# Display Actions Only For Specific Folders

Tags: plone

I have added a custom CMF Action at /mysite/portal_actions/object/rename. The value for "Condition (Expression)" field is `python:plone_context_state.is_folderish() or plone_context_state.is_default_page()`, that makes the action visible on every folder's tab. I want it show only on tabs of folder1, folder2 and folder3. What should I use for Condition field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options; the condition expression can be extended almost infinitely.

### By folder id

The obvious test would be to test for a set of folder ids:

```
python:(plone_context_state.is_folderish() or plone_context_state.is_default_page()) and
        folder.getId() in ('folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3')
```

### Use [collective.flag](http://plone.org/products/collective.flag)

[collective.flag](http://plone.org/products/collective.flag) let's your content editors determine where the tab should show up. It adds a simple boolean checkbox to your content, and you could easily test for that flag being set on your folders. The flag only shows up on content types that have the correct interface, so you could easily do this

```
python:(plone_context_state.is_folderish() or plone_context_state.is_default_page()) and 
        folder.restrictedTraverse('@@plone_interface_info').provides('collective.flag.interfaces.IFlaggableObject')
```

### Use a script test

You can use any acquirable method for your test, including a Python script in the skin. Not the best practice, but it may just give you the extra flexibility you need.

```
python:(plone_context_state.is_folderish() or plone_context_state.is_default_page()) and
        folder.yourScriptName()
```

Just remember to test for conditions on `folder`.

Answer (score -1):

python:(plone_context_state.is_folderish() and (object.getId() == 'folder1' or object.getId() == 'folder2' or object.getId() == 'folder3')) or (plone_context_state.is_default_page() and (plone_context_state.parent.getId() == 'folder1' or plone_context_state.parent.getId() == 'folder2' or plone_context_state.parent.getId() == 'folder3'))

something like this. You can use the folder path to be sure they're exacly those folders and not just folders with those ids.

Comment: 2 problems with this expression: first of all, if this is the default page it will never match as the default page id is different from the folder id, and secondly, you should use `.getId()` as `.id` is almost always an attribute, but sometimes it's a function. `.getId()` is the official API.

Comment: that was why I've stated "something like this". About the default page, we have to change in: python:(plone_context_state.is_folderish() and (object.getId() == 'folder1' or object.getId() == 'folder2' or object.getId() == 'folder3')) or (plone_context_state.is_default_page() and (plone_context_state.parent.getId() == 'folder1' or plone_context_state.parent.getId() == 'folder2' or plone_context_state.parent.getId() == 'folder3')). Martijn, are you happier now? :)

Comment: Why not just use `folder`? That is after all either the current object or the nearest parent that is a folder! :-) Also, why not use .getId() in (set-of-ids)?

Comment: Because I didn't remember about it :) about ".getId() in (set-of-ids)" I agree, it is better.